# Distributing n identical balls into k distinct boxes when the number of boxes is greater than the number of balls and any box can have zero balls

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

Distributing n identical balls into k distinct boxes when the number of boxes is greater than the number of balls and any box can have zero balls.

For eg distributing 4 balls in 7 boxes and any box can contain zero balls

What would be the general formula for this?

Comment: This is covered by [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#:~:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20combinatorial,his%20classic%20book%20on%20probability.)

Comment: See also this [2nd Stars and Bars article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/).